# Magento all products become out of stock after import

Tags: magento, import

I am having a very frustrating problem with Magento import.  I just encountered this problem recently after several times of doing import without any issue.  I have two different csv files but almost have the same content which I use to import the products. The only diffrence is the 'is_in_stock' column.  I use import to update the products quantity of our online store.

This csv file sets the products to Out of Stock:
[outofstock-issue.csv](http://jigsawpuzzleworld.com.sg/csv_converter/outofstock-issue.csv)

This one correctly sets the product' stock availability: [outofstock-issue-2.csv](http://jigsawpuzzleworld.com.sg/csv_converter/outofstock-issue-2.csv)

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Have you tried reindex?